# How to find where zoom is getting MAC

Tags: debian, mac-address

It looks like based on stdout output after running a malicious app called zoom, that it gathers the currently used MAC Address. I am looking to block this functionality via AppArmor, however I cant discover how its finding the MAC. Ive looked through my whitelist and found nothing related to networking or a MAC address. How can I discover the method used To discover the MAC address. Im on Debian 10

Comment: Try using `strace -fF`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that during installation of the Zoom package, it finds the MAC address somewhere and then writes it to a config file in `~/.config/zoomus.conf`, where it is listed as the Device ID. Modifying this ID causes the app to read the MAC as whatever is in the conf file, it also doesn't need to adhere to MAC address standards if you decide to modify it :).